# How to select a file in finder in Xamarin?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am trying to select a file in the Finder, that is not happening the method works well in Obj-C but in Xamarin Finder gets activated but the file is not getting selected.

Whereas if I use Xamarin command to open the file it opens.

Here is the snippet of code that I wrote. Guide me if I am doing something wrong or missing anything?

```
public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
{

    string fullPath = "/Users/anoopvaidya/Desktop/A/ClientInfoConfig.cs";

    NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString(fullPath);

    NSUrl[] urls = { url };


    NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile(fullPath); 
   //works. But I only want to select in Finder

    NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.ActivateFileViewer(urls); 
   //doesn't work

}
```

Is it related to OS version? I am using 10.13.6.

Comment: `Whereas if I use Xamarin command to open the file it opens.` What exactly do you mean here?

Comment: @G.hakim: Open means, if I pass .cs it opens in VS, if I pass .jpg it opens in preview. i.e. the file opens in the default app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `file://` based url:

#### Example:

```
using (var url = new NSUrl("file", "localhost", "/Users/Sushi/Desktop/StackOverflow.png"))
{
    NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.ActivateFileViewer(new NSUrl[] { url });
}
```